# Convergence of conditional probabilities for weakly convergent stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, limits-and-convergence

**Note:** I am happy to refine the question if more details or context is needed. Any hints even are greatly appreciated. I'll offer a bounty soon, but don't have must reputation to give. I could move the questions to MathSE where I have more reputation to give for bounty, but I think this is a real research-level problem so it is maybe more appropriate here.

Consider a stochastic process $X=(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ with unique stationary distribution $\pi$. Hence $X_t\Rightarrow \pi$ as $t\to\infty$ in the standard weak convergence sense. Suppose we (disjointly) partition the time index interval $[0,\infty)=\cup_{j=0}^\infty I_j$. Also let $\mathbb P_X$ the distribution of $X$, and let $A_j$ be an event that only asks about the states of the process at times in the interval $I_j$. Let $Y_t$ be a stationary process with stationary distribution $\pi$ and $\mathbb P_Y$ the distribution for process $Y=(Y_t)_{t\geq0}$. Assume the processes have sample paths in $\Omega=S^{[0,\infty)}$ with states at each time in $S$.

Q1: It seems clear to me that $|\mathbb P_X(A_j)-\mathbb P_Y(A_j)|\to0$ as $j\to\infty$. Is this true, and if so do I need any kind of justification?

Q2: Under what conditions do we have that $|\mathbb P_X(A_n\mid A_{n-1}\cdots A_0)-\mathbb P_Y(A_n\mid A_{n-1}\cdots A_0)|$ decays to zero as $n\to\infty$? Seems like we just need the boundary of each of these events to be zero, yes? Under what conditions is this difference *decreasing* in $n$?

I am interested in the more general case, but specifically the following case first and foremost. Consider some arbitrary point process $X_t$ (with unique stationary distribution $\pi$), and let the events $A_j$ all be increasing events, e.g. $A_j=\{\text{at least $n_j$ points in interval $I_j$}\}$. Let $Y_t$ be a stationary point process with distribution $\pi$ (e.g. a Poisson point process with constant arrival rate $\lambda$). Assume that $Y_t$ stochastically dominates $X_t$. Retain the domination, uniqueness of stationary distribution, and increasing events; does that have any impact on the answers to the questions?

I am viewing this as simulating these processes in discrete chunks on the intervals $I_j$ in sequence with a coupling that realizes the stochastic domination. As the simulation progresses, we check whether or not the events $A_j$ have occurred. The domination means that when $A_j$ occurs for $X_t$, then it also does for $Y_t$ (the coupled versions of these processes), etc.

Clearly $\mathbb P_X (A_j)$ gets close to $\mathbb P_Y (A_j)$ as $j$ increases (Q1 above), yes? How does conditioning affect this convergence in this specific case (Q2 above)?

What I really want is that $|\mathbb P_X(A_n\mid A_{n-1}\cdots A_0)-\mathbb P_Y(A_n\mid A_{n-1}\cdots A_0)|$ is decreasing in $n$. Clearly $\mathbb P_X(A_n)\leq\mathbb P_Y(A_n)$ for all $n$ due to the assumption that $Y$ dominates $X$ and the $A_j$ are each increasing events. But do I also get that $\mathbb P_X(A_n\mid A_{n-1}\cdots A_0)\leq\mathbb P_Y(A_n\mid A_{n-1}\cdots A_0)$ for all $n$? The answer seems obviously "yes" to me since $Y$ dominates $X$ and that $X$ satisfying some $A_j$ automatically implies $Y$ does as well (the coupled versions of these processes).

What if I only condition on some subcollection of the $A_j$? E.g. let $J_n$ be some list of natural numbers whose max value grows as $n$ increases, then do we get $\mathbb P_X(A_n\mid \cap_{j\in J_n} A_j)\leq\mathbb P_Y(A_n\mid \cap_{j\in J_n} A_j)$ for all $n$ (and that the difference between them decays to zero)? For example, let $J_n=\{1, n,n+1, n^2\}$. Seems like it shouldn't matter, the coupling preserves the ordering no matter what the history of the processes happens to be (of course a history allowed by the coupling, which exhibits the domination).